# Finding which guess is closest to random number

Tags: java

Given this requirement

> Create a code which creates random number and ask user to make 2 guess and then print out the actual number and also state which one of your guess was closest

I am stuck at the last part. Please help.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package selectionexercises;

/**
 *
 *
 * @author jhonpaul
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("I have picked a number between 1 to 100 try to guess it.");
        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        System.out.println("Enter Your First Guess.");
        int guess1;
        guess1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Second Guess.");
        int guess2;
        guess2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number was " + randomNumber);
        int range;
        range = randomNumber;



    }
}
```

Comment: By closest, it means which guess gives the lower number when calculating the absolute value of the difference between the guess and target number.

Comment: by closest i mean which one of the guesses is close to the random number

Comment: If you already know how to calculate the "closest" guess, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.min(Math.abs(randomNumber-guess1), Math.abs(randomNumber-guess2))

Comment: and how do i print it on the screen

Comment: @jhon You already printing things to the screen.  What don't you understand about how you are already doing this that you can't do it again?

Comment: if (Math.abs(randomNumber-guess1)<Math.abs(randomNumber-guess2)){System.out.println("The first  was closer");} else {System.out.println("The second was closer");}

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
//Calculate difference and use absolute value (turn negative values into positive if necessary)
int difference1 = Math.abs(randomNumber - guess1)
int difference2 = Math.abs(randomBumber - guess2)

//Compare result
if(difference1<difference2) {
    System.out.println("Guess1 was closer"); 
} else if (difference1>difference2) {
    System.out.println("Guess2 was closer"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("Both were equally close!"); 
}
```

There are shorter ways than this but scince you are a starter I think this is an understandable and easy to use way.

Comment: This did work thank you very much